# How to add some property to OData query result?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am working on a webapi project and i used OData for manipulating the result of my apis.
Now, I have a problem. I want to add some property to my result.
Suppose this is the normal result:

```
[{
   TotalPrice: 69000,
   Id : 1
},
{
  TotalPrice: 51000,
  Id : 2
}]
```

Now, I want to have a `json` like this:

```
{
   Orders : [{
             TotalPrice: 69000,
             Id : 1
           },
           {
             TotalPrice: 51000,
             Id : 2
           }],
   GrandTotal : 120000
}
```

without affecting the OData Query functionality. How?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the open type and dynamic property?